# How to schedule a bash file in cron jobs on linux

Tags: python, cron

i am trying to schedule a bash script `(cron.sh)` in cron jobs below is my bash script code

**cron.sh**: (Please correct it if something wrong)

```
#!/bin/bash 
#chmod +x cron.sh

cd ~/main_file/folders/douys
python -u cron.py
```

Please let me know how to make a bash file executable

Here cron.sh file runs some python file, and when i run the bash script `(cron.sh)` with the following command it works fine and python file is executing

```
sh cron.sh
```

But i want to schedule the above `cron.sh` file in crons jobs to run for every two mins

can anyone let me know how to do above

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning that, if your .sh is just a "wrapper" for the .py, you can add the following line to the beginning of you Python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

And then make it executable:

```
$> chmod a+x code.py
```

Then you can add directly your Python file as a cronjob following the instruction that m4573r explained. (of course, '~/cron.sh' becomes 'path/to/cron.py').

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule the job by running `crontab -e` and adding the following line in the end: 
`*/2 * * * * /path/to/cron.sh`.

You should read `man cron` for more informations.

Comment: in the above command near cron.sh we need to give the total path of the bash file where it exists right ?